# Issue in creating a simple DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt

I was just trying to familiarise myself to GWT DataGrid, I read the examples given in **javadoc** also. The strange thing is **in DataGrid example they are using CellTable** 
Is this just a typo or is it intentional?

Also I have copied the following code from javadoc which works fine in case of CellTable but as soon as I replace CellTable with DataGrid it stops working.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
public class DataGridPOC implements EntryPoint {

  DataGrid<Contact> table = new DataGrid<Contact>();


  /**
   * A simple data type that represents a contact.
   */
  private static class Contact {
    private final String address;
    private final Date birthday;
    private final String name;

    public Contact(String name, Date birthday, String address) {
      this.name = name;
      this.birthday = birthday;
      this.address = address;
    }
  }

  /**
   * The list of data to display.
   */
  private static final List<Contact> CONTACTS = Arrays.asList(
      new Contact("John", new Date(80, 4, 12), "123 Fourth Avenue"),
      new Contact("Joe", new Date(85, 2, 22), "22 Lance Ln"),
      new Contact("George", new Date(46, 6, 6), "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue"));

  public void onModuleLoad() {

 // Add a text column to show the name.
    TextColumn<Contact> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Contact>() {
      @Override
      public String getValue(Contact object) {
        return object.name;
      }
    };
    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");

    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Birthday");

    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Address");

    // Set the total row count. This isn't strictly necessary, but it affects
    // paging calculations, so its good habit to keep the row count up to date.
    table.setRowCount(CONTACTS.size(), true);

    // Push the data into the widget.
    table.setRowData(0, CONTACTS);

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get().add(table);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop working"?

Comment: well, the table does not show up, in case of data grid.

Comment: Try to set the height explicitly: table.setHeight("100px"); and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the reason for this behaviour is that we need to explicitly specify the 
Height of the grid.

```
 table.setHeight("300px");
```

this showed my table. It is not mentioned anywhere in the [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html). Also, the example there is using CellTable insted of DataGrid. :)

Please feel free to make corrections, it might help someone.

Thanks

Comment: It's not the problem with JavaDoc. If you add your table to a LayoutTable as a layer, or any other widget that provides size to its children, you don't need to specify the height of the DataGrid. By the way, you don't need to set its width for it to show up in your example.